# Mongoose populate funciton on array

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a problem with populate in mongoose function,
here is my Schemas:

event.js file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Event = new Schema({
  name:  String, 
  posts: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Post",
  }]
  
});

module.exports =  mongoose.model('Events',Event);
```

post.js file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Post = new Schema({
  name: String,
  content: String,
  picture: String
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Posts',Post)
```

when adding new post to an event i use this route and do the following :

```
router.post("/:id",async (req,res)=>{
    let id = req.params.id;
    const postToAdd = new Post({
        name : req.body.name ,
        content: req.body.content,
        picture: req.body.picture,
    });

    postToAdd.save().then((err,res)=>{
        if(err) console.log(err)
        else console.log(err)
    })

    const evetToUpdate = await event.findById(id)
    evetToUpdate.posts.push(postToAdd)
    const newEvent = await evetToUpdate.save()
    
    event.findById(id).
    populate('posts').
    exec(function(err,res){
        if(err) console.log(err)
        else console.log(res.Post)
    })
   
})
```

The result of this process is that i have an new post that linked to the event put without the populated data.

Comment: try populate('posts')

Comment: getting an error :     Schema hasn't been registered for model "Post"

Comment: try to look at the creation of the schema, it could be that your schema creates as Posts not Post

Answer (score 0):

okey,
foolish mistake,
in the ref i needed to mention the exact name of the collection, Post.